# Use Powershell to find and compare text in file to a folder name

Tags: powershell

My apologies, but unfortunately my Powershell scripting is quite poor, however I'm trying to muddle on with this... The below is actually for a Nagios check, hence the defining the OK, WARNING etc

**Summary**

I have 2 small text files with specific text within that I need to check for a folder existing with the corresponding name.

In File 1 below, note the section that states "prod" on line 18, against this I am interested in the apples, pears and bananas data (that which is a date format, plus other text) within the speech marks, so for bananas it would be **20220817-1-64** only.

- The position within the text file of the "prod" line and subsequent data I'm
  interested in can't be guaranteed.
- The data against apples, pears etc will change over time

file1.txt:

```
{
"default": "prod",
"pre": {
    "apples": "20220711-0",
    "pears": "20220711-0",
    "bananas": "20220711-1-64"
},
"test": {
    "apples": "20220920-0",
    "pears": "20220920-0",
    "bananas": "20220920-1-64"
},
"new": {
    "apples": "20220910-0",
    "pears": "20220910-0",
    "bananas": "20220910-1-64"
},
"prod": {
    "apples": "20220817-0",
    "pears": "20220210-0",
    "bananas": "20220817-1-64"
},
"old": {
    "apples": "20220601-0",
    "pears": "20220601-0",
    "bananas": "20220601-1-64"
}
}
```

File 2 has a similar principal, I am only interested in **20220923-0** next to the "prod" line (again, position within the file can't be guaranteed and the data will change over time)

File2.txt:

```
{
"default": "prod",
"pre": "20220917-0",
"test": "20220926-0",
"new": "20220924-0",
"prod": "20220923-0"
}
```

Each of the values would need to be compared against a directory, to see if a folder of the same name exists. If it matches, the result would be OK, if different then result in a WARNING, if missing the result would be CRITICAL.

**What I have tried**

Defining the result and folder to check against is straight forward enough:

```
# Result
$OK=0
$WARNING=1
$CRITICAL=2

# Folders to check
$apples_folder = (Get-Childitem c:\folder_path\apples\*).Name
$pears_folder = (Get-Childitem c:\folder_path\pears\*).Name
```

However the main part I'm struggling with is picking out the relevant text from the text file(s) against the prod line(s)

From what I have gathered, I suspect using regex or possibly grep commands may hold the answer, but I can't quite get my head around it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: File1.txt contains what looks like JSON, but it is missing the final closing bracket `}`. If that is just a typo, you can use `ConvertFrom-Json` on the content and find the value you need using dot notation `$json.prod.bananas`.
File2.txt has a weird format and to parse that, you could use the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet on it, provided you have removed the commas and quotes first (and if working with PowerShell 5.x, replaced the colons `:` by equal signs `=`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can parse File1.txt as JSON, assuming that what you gave us as example is missing the final closing bracket '}' as a result of posting it here and that the json in the actual file is complete.

To work with that file type, you can do

```
$json = Get-Content -Path 'X:\somewhere\File1.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$prodFolder = $json.prod.bananas
# next test if you can find a folder with that name and do whatever you need to do then
if (Test-Path -Path "c:\folder_path\prod\$prodFolder" -PathType Container) {
    "OK"
}
else {
    "CRITICAL"
}
```

For File2.txt, things are quite different because that is a strange format..
What you can do is convert the data in there into a Hashtable using the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet.

In PowerShell 5.x you need to replace the colons that separate the names from their values into an equal sign (`=`)

```
$data = (Get-Content -Path 'X:\somewhereElse\File2.txt' -Raw) -replace '^(.*?):(.*)','$1=$2' -replace '[", ]' | ConvertFrom-StringData
$prodFolder = $data.prod
# next test if you can find a folder with that name and do whatever you need to do then
if (Test-Path -Path "c:\folder_path\prod\$prodFolder" -PathType Container) {
    "OK"
}
else {
    "CRITICAL"
}
```

In PowerShell 7.x you do not have to replace the colons:

```
$data = (Get-Content -Path 'X:\somewhereElse\File2.txt' -Raw) -replace '[", ]' | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':'
```

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for the response. Yes file1 is json and I omitted the last closing bracket.

Comment: Incidentally, file2 is actually json too, however regardless, I have got part way there with the 2nd file, as I need to determine what the data is next prod is, the following gets me part way there: `$oranges_target = Get-ChildItem -Path I:\file2.json | Select-String -Pattern '"prod":'` returns: `I:\file2.json:6:    "prod": "20220923-0",` - Need to single out just the **20220923-0** and compare against my folder name.

Comment: @foobar Then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73855023/edit) and show File2 in the correct (json) structure. When working with structured data, you should not use textualk searches on it. Instead, use the same principle for File2 as I did above on File1 and convert the file to **object**, so you can simply use its properties

Comment: I have edited both file contents and have tried the principal as described for file1 against file2, however regardless of whether the folder is the same name as the data against prod (20220923-0) or not, it still returns OK

Comment: @foobar In File2, there is no `.bananas` and the final comma in this line `"prod": "20220923-0",` shouldn't be there.  Please take some more care with what you post as example because I still have the idea we're only looking at some minor part of the structure which makes it almost impossible to give you the correct answer

Comment: Yes there was some other guff past `"prod": "20220923-0",` however it made little difference to the outcome. With your assistance I have managed to get it to run against the file data perfectly.